# Shapely deprecation warning message when plotting GeoPandas geodataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a GeoPandas geodataframe as I always do. Now I am having a new pc when I try to plot my geodataframe using : `gdf.plot()` there is no plot displayed and I receive this message:

> C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\descartes\patch.py:62: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0. Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I tried uninstalling geopandas, earthpy and shapely afterwards I reinstalled geopandas==0.10, earthpy==0.9.4 and shapely==1.7.0. It worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

( **Answer for users who ended up here based on the title and just want to hide the error** )

If you have acknowledged the error and do not want it to keep appearing, you can always ignore it using :

```
import shapely
import warnings
from shapely.errors import ShapelyDeprecationWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ShapelyDeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Too bad they did not add their warnins to the official category of `DeprecationWarning`'s

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is almoast the same solution I have done. The error was due to non compatible versions of used modules. So I reinstall everthing with the latest versions.